# how to change the CSS value of the padding and margin in the WP vertical menu items

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i gat this situation, (WordPrsee with OceanWP Theme).

[image]

i want to change the height + padding + margin + the total height size of the nav.
i tryed use CSS in the global CSS like :

```
.menu-item-497 a {
    height: 40px !important;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 20px; !important;
    line-height: 135% !important;
}

li.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-498 {
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 20px; !important;
}
```

this does not work.

i tryed set CSS Class and add some CSS in the GLOBAL CSS Area
also tried change the custom CSS "name" in the advance tab of the all navigator and this didn't help too.
also tried to use the CSS ID too.
also tried change in the MENU tab at the appearance sub menu.

what is the proper way to change it.
when I set the value in the chrome debug mode (F12) that work.

[image]

and this work :
[image]

so - what is the way of using CSS in Wordpress and fix those prop value I want.

thanks, foreplay.

Answer (score 0):

ok.

i read the https://presscustomizr.com/snippet/adding-css-classes-wordpress-menu page
.

this explains how to see CSS  Class for that item  (you can set items with the  same class)

after setting  the class name - I  goto  general CSS.

there set :

.

```
hanibaal-Footer-MenuItem{
    height: 40px !important;
/*      padding: 2px 20px 2px 20px; !important; */
/*      line-height: 135% !important; */
}

li.hanibaal-Footer-MenuItem.menu-item a {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px !important; 
}
```

and that work.

[image]